# Second Footer Line in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I was wondering if we could have a second footer line (below the author's name, short title, date, and the number of the slide) in beamer like the one below? If so, I would welcome any ideas so as to try it.

[image]

Comment: To answer your question: Yes we could.

Comment: The place to work on is `\setbeamertemplate{footline}`. Sorry if I'm annoying you, but I'm tired and going to bed now and don't have enough energy left to give better answers.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an additional line by redefining the footline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%

    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot} text
  \end{beamercolorbox}%  
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! There is an error showing: "! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \ifblank " when I'm trying to run it.

Comment: @Y_gr Works for me without error. How are you compiling? Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: TeXworks and I compiled it with pdfLaTeX

Comment: @Y_gr Which version? I used pdflatex from texlive 2017.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why did you add the `\vskip0pt` to the bottom of the `footline`?

Comment: @Skillmon `\vskip0pt`  comes from `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`.  Not sure if it serves some deeper purpose there...