# Beamer footer shifted by adding an \if... \fi test

Tags: beamer, conditionals

Ok --- I am getting crazy about this (I can workaround it, but I really would like to know what's happening). Consider this MWE copied almost straight from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400268/38080):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  %%\ifnum\thepage>1\relax  %%% HERE
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%

    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot} text
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip0pt%
  %%\fi %%% HERE
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which renders ok:

[image: Correct rendering]

But I do not want the footer on the titlepage, (in my theme it has a background image), so I uncomment the `\ifnum...\fi` comment above with `%%%HERE`. The footer disappear correctly in the first frame, but then all the other frames footer is displaced:

[image: Wrong rendering]

...what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

if your footer had no text then it would be equivalent to

```
\leavevmode\hbox{}%
\vskip0pt
```

Which starts a paragraph, adds a white line of "text" ends the paragraph and then adds a vertical skip of 0pt (which potentially moves the alignment point).

Your `\ifnum` replaces that by nothing, which means that the behaviour is likely to be different, move the test inside your hbox.

Note that in general it isn't safe to test the page counter mid document or test `\thepage` as a number, but as you are in beamer with no automatic page breaking and you know the page style is numeric it's OK (although I would use `\value{page}` not `\thepage` for safety).

Comment: Yes, I tried it... still the same behavior. Must be some low-level interaction with beamer code... Basically, the problem arises where the test is true, not false --- the test succeeds in removing the footer on the first page, but then adds something unexpected when it is true.

Comment: @Rmano actually I didn't try, no time at present I'll test later and fix or delete. (Actually what I say above is correct, you need at least this, but maybe need a bit more....)

Comment: @david-carslisle seems a problem about the height of the footer: beamer do the calculation on the first slide, and my `\if...\fi` is throwing it astray. Noticed in chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47349086#47349086